# CKEditor bbcode and codesnippet plugins, wrong [code]

Tags: ckeditor, bbcode

I use *CKEditor* with *bbcode* and *codesnippet* plugins, but every time the editor removes the class for `code`.

I must do something like this:

```
[code=javascript]sddsds[/code]
```

But everytime it results in this:

```
[code]dfdfd[/code]
```

Plugins:

- http://ckeditor.com/addon/codesnippet
- http://ckeditor.com/addon/bbcode

Any ideas about how to solve this issue?

Comment: The bbcode plugin is not compatible with codesnippet. You would need to modify to make it work.

Comment: Yes i update bbcode, and works now

Comment: If you shared the changes that you made with others as an answer to your question, you could accept it.

Answer (score 1):

is very easy if someone has the same issue like me

First update : attributesMap

```
attributesMap = { url: 'href', email: 'mailhref', quote: 'cite', list: 'listType', code: 'class' };
```

After this in proto object you have attribute function and change it with

```
attribute: function( name, val ) {

            if ( name == 'option' ) {
                // Force simply ampersand in attributes.
                if ( typeof val == 'string' )
                    val = val.replace( /&amp;/g, '&' );

                this.write( '=', val );
            }

            if (name == 'class') {

                this.write( '=', val );
            }
        }
```

That is all :D

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
[js]dfdfd[/js]
```

Comment: the main idea is use default plugins, not create new plugins